# How to fix the "SQLServerException: The connection is closed." occurrence in this Try-With-Resources block?

Tags: java, jdbc, try-with-resources

I am doing a performance testing of a DBMS. I have to do it manually for my master thesis. I have to have a certain number of threads, each of them opening its own JDBC connection to the db (connection pooling is not an option) and committing the same number of the same transactions (each thread does the same job). I have my connection opened as a resource in `try-with-resources` block. The connection should stay opened until the end of the `try-with-resources` scope, but sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.

```
try (Connection conn = getConn();
    PreparedStatement simpleSelectStmt = conn
                         .prepareStatement(tcInstance.getQueryMap().get("SimpleSelect").getSimpleSelect())) {

        setConnIsolation(conn);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        singleThread.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int j = 0; j < tcInstance.getnT(); j++) {
                    try {
                        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                        simpleSelectStmt.execute();
                        conn.commit();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        error++;
                        if (detectDeadlock(e.getMessage())) {
                            deadlock++;
                            System.out.println("Deadlock detected!");
                        } else {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            if (conn != null) {
                                conn.rollback();
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            System.out.println("There was an error in rolling back the transaction.");
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    if (j != (tcInstance.getnT() - 1)) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(t);// ms
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                measureCPUusage(Thread.currentThread().getId());
                singleThread.shutdown();

        });

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        ....doing some other measurements....

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error");
    }
```

This is the `getConn()` method used for getting the jdbc connection:

```
private Connection getConn() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(tcInstance.getJDBCurl(), tcInstance.getUser(), tcInstance.getPassword());
}
```

I expected the connection to be opened through entire try-with-resources block, but there are Connection is closed exceptions on the lines `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` and `conn.rollback();`

Comment: Shouldn't each thread have its own connection?

Comment: Yes, they should. I am having one connection per thread and all of the transactions of that thread (nT of them) are sharing that  one connection. At least I think I am having it like that. Am I doing it wrong? For the background: this whole try-with-resources block is inside of a work() method of a class which represents one thread, that class is being instantiated in each iteration of the loop in the Main class.

Comment: You should move the `try-with-resource` into the `singleThread.execute` method

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as you've suggested and the exception is no longer occurring. I would like to up vote your comment but I need 15 reputation for that option to be enabled (I am new here)... Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code flow in short seems to be something like this:

```
try (Connection conn = getConn()) {
    setConnIsolation(conn);

    // Posted from Thread-1
    singleThread.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        // Thread-2 accesses conn created on Thread-1
        // use conn here..
    });

   // ....doing some other work....

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error");
}

//Conn is released
```

By the time, the runnable starts its work, its corresponding thread may be using a conn that has been released. This is because, the posting thread, after posting the runnable, comes out of the Try-With-Resources block and as a part of it, the Conn is released.

Solution:
Bring the Conn out of the Try-With-Resources Block.

Answer (score 0):

Please open separate connection for each thread. Your open connection for one thread getting closed by another thread and hence you are getting the exception.Also, Please provide more information about detectDeadlock to assist you further. I hope that you do not require such things for simple connections in multi threaded environments.